# Same BAT file behaving differently when called from Desktop or from within a Program

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm using Windows 7. I want to trigger a BAT file to run once some sound happens.

The BAT file should trigger a Skype call.

For that, I'm using the following BAT command:

```
c:\"Program Files"\Skype\Phone\skype /callto:someUsername
```

Skype should be already running before the trigger. If I double-click this BAT file on my desktop, it will run smoothly, pop up Skype, and start the call.

Now I'm using [ISpy software](http://www.ispyconnect.com/) to trigger the BAT file over a specified sound threshold.

ISpy is working fine. It detects the sound and triggers the BAT file.
But when the BAT file starts running, instead of popping up Skype it tries to load a new Skype instance.

Is there a context difference between calling BAT file with double click or within ISpy?

How can I overcome this?

Comment: there should be no difference. Are you sure you run under the same userid?

Comment: yes, just tested outside and inside ISpy

Comment: How are you calling the batch file from iSpy?

Comment: Hi, i could already solve the problem.
Even though i have administrator rights, when running ISpy i did not have all permissions enabled.

If i change this in the security preferences than the batch file runs smoothly.

Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Could be the difference between a 32-bit "CMD.exe" and a 64-bit "cmd.exe". When you run  a batch file, a cmd.exe is started to read and execute it. Depending on who starts the CMD.exe you may get a 32 bit version or a 64 bit version. You can tell by looking at the env-var PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE. I think starting it from Explorer you will usually get the 64bit version. You can start a 32-bit cmd.exe by running "C:\Windows\Syswow64\Cmd.exe"

Answer (score 1):

@PaulojFonseca hasn't checked in since one day after this post, meaning Oct 29, 2012, so he won't likely come back to post his answer. Even though he won't be here to accept his *own* answer, I'll post it so at least it will show up. I've edited it to make the answer easier to read without much context.

"... when running ISpy, ... not all permissions [that were needed were] enabled. If i change this in the security preferences than the batch file runs smoothly."